# How implement 'include' into printf?

Tags: php

I use in project such functions:

```
include ("blocks/myCompanyCommentsListBlock.php");
```

I need somethig like this:

```
$str = sprintf("<div>%s</div>", include ("blocks/myCompanyCommentsListBlock.php"));
```

How this can be done? :) Any links would be useful :)

Comment: do you want the full contents of "myCompanyCommentsListBlock.php" [file_get_contents()] ? or is it php code to run ?

Comment: Use functions. Put the code of the include file in a function, include it before the assignment and call the function in the assignment.

Comment: @jeroen: to be precise - you *can* `return` from a file.

Comment: Can this not be done by `echo '<div>'; include 'inc.php'; echo '</div>';` ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use output buffering to prevent its content from being sent to the browser. Then use [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to capture its output into a variable.

```
ob_start();
include ("blocks/myCompanyCommentsListBlock.php");
$content = ob_get_clean();
$str = sprintf("<div>%s</div>", $content);
```

Comment: @zerkms That's what I was looking for. I had done this once *years* ago and forgot exactly what it was I did.

Comment: Useful to write note to remember this :)